# Why would a function defined in the same class be considered undeclared? How to declare it properly?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting the error "undeclared identifier" on the commented line:

```
- (BOOL) isInIntArray:(NSInteger[])array theElem:(int)elem{
    int i = 0;
    NSInteger sizeOfArray = (sizeof array) / (sizeof array[0]);
    while(i < sizeOfArray){
        if(array[i] == elem){
            return TRUE;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

- (int)getNextUnusedID{
    int i = rand()%34;
    while ([isInIntArray:idsUsed theElem:i]) { //here: Use of undeclared identifier 'isInIntArray'
        i = rand()%34;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I really don't understand why, they are in the same `.m` file.
Why would that be?

Also, this code:

```
NSInteger sizeOfArray = (sizeof array) / (sizeof array[0]);
```

is giving me the warning:

> Sizeof on array function will return Sizeof 'NSInteger *' (aka: 'int *') instead of 'NSInteger[]'"

How should I properly determine the size of an array?

Comment: Whole approach is wrong. It doesn't work this way. I guess you came from some scripting language or C++. You should use objects (`NSArray` and `NSNumber`).

Comment: To the 2nd question: The warning should be self-explanatory: Your variable array is not an array, but a pointer to an array, and sizeof will thus give you the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @CaptainRedmuff pointed out, you are missing the target object in method invocation, that is `self`.

```
//[object methodParam:x param:y];

[self isInIntArray:idsUsed theElem:i];
```

---

To your second Q. In *C language* you cannot determine the size of an array. That's why they are not used, since we have objects for this. I recommend you to use these:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // to create array
array[0] = @42; // to set value at index, `@` creates objects, in this case NSNumber
[array insertObject:@42 atindex:0]; // equivalent to the above
NSInteger integer = array[0].integerValue; // get the value, call integerMethod to get plain int
integer = [[array objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]; // equivalent to the above
[array containsObject:@42]; // test if given object is in the array
[array indexOfObject:@42]; // get index of object from array, NSNotFound if not found
array.count; // to get the number of objects
```

**Important:** These arrays have variable size and they are not limited! But you can access elements only at indexes *0..(n-1)* (where *n* in number of objects) and you can set values only for indexes *0..n*.
In other words, you can not do `array[3] = @42;` for empty array, you need to fill first 3 positions first (indexes 0, 1 and 2).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you've missed out `self` from this line

```
while ([isInIntArray:idsUsed theElem:i])
```

This should be:

```
while ([self isInIntArray:idsUsed theElem:i])
```

Comment: CaptainRedmuff is right. As explanation: isInIntArray:theElem: is not a function but a method that has to be sent to an object in which it is defined, here self.

Comment: Thank you, I did not noticed a difference between 'self.' and 'self '. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

write this in .h file (declare the function)

```
    - (BOOL) isInIntArray:(NSInteger[])array theElem:(int)elem;
```

and call the method using following way

```
    while ([self isInIntArray:idsUsed theElem:i]) { //here: Use of undeclared identifier 'isInIntArray'
            i = rand()%34;
    }
```